# Azure 4k live streaming

Tags: azure, video-streaming, azure-media-services

The situation is: i want to send live RTMP, 4k60fps 80Mb/s stream from my computer to Live Azure Encoder and later stream to YouTube/Facebook etc. In specs i found, that Live Azure Encoder can receive up to FHD30fps. Is there any possibility to send stream with my parameters mentioned above? 
If no, can I achieve my goal using different Azure components?

Greetings,
Konrad

Comment: Have you tried ?

Comment: Yes i did. It's as I said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the live encoder in Azure Media Services does not support 4k ingest. You can send 4Kp60 streams to our pass-through LiveEvent, though - either with H.264 codec or H.265/HEVC. You will need an encoder (eg. MediaExcel) that generates a multiple bitrate 4K/HEVC feed and sends it to our services. Please contact us directly via amshelp@microsoft.com if you want to discuss options.